# How to measure peak memory usage of a process tree?

Tags: linux, memory

By a process tree I mean the process and everything it executes in any way.

I tried `/usr/bin/time -v`, but the results are entirely wrong. For example running a `npm test` in one of our projects with 14GiB free RAM and 8GiB of free swap results in OOM killer starting to kill my applications (most commonly a browser and IDE). `time` reports only 800MiB was used, even though the real memory consumption must have been very high, over 20GiB...

Answer (score 4):

First I would pickup the process with the `smem`.  For example, you could use `smem -tas uss` to have an overview.

- `-t` ... shows totals
- `-a` ... auto adjusts the column width
- `-s uss`... sorts the result based on the *uss* column

To see details per process the best way is to use `pmap`.  To get detailed information you should use `-X` switch.  To get all information that kernel provides you can use `-XX` which usually is an overkill.

To get a 2 seconds refresh monitoring for a *pid* 3120:

`watch -n 2 pmap -X 3120`

**Edit: To actually get a peak**  The above helps in monitoring, but it does not show an actual peak. Slipped my mind.

I would personally use `valgrind` with the `massif` tool.

`valgrind --tool=massif --pages-as-heap=yes --massif-out-file=evolution_massif.out evolution; grep mem_heap_B evolution_massif.out | sed -e 's/mem_heap_B=\(.*\)/\1/' | sort -g | tail -n 1`

Explanation:

- `--page-as-heap=yes` ... tells massif that it should take all memory instead of just heap
- `--massif-out-file` ... the output file for the *massif* tool
- **evolution** ... the application that should be monitored

The next part is there to find out the maximum number recorded.

The `grep` searches for *mem_heap_B* occurrences. `sed -e` gets rid of the string `mem_heap_B` so we get only numeric result.  The we sort it via `sort -g` which is generic numeric sort and take the biggest number with `tail -n 1` which returns the first line of the sorted numbers.

After the application is terminated `valgrid` will printout one number, which is the memory peak in [B]ytes.

### Check the memory peak logging

To display the output file *evolution_massif.out*, you can use `ms_print` post-processing tool for Massif.

It is simply:

`ms_print evolution_massif.out`

The output should look like this (this is first page of the output), where you can see which snapshot was a peak - **10 (peak)**:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Command:            evolution
Massif arguments:   --pages-as-heap=yes --massif-out-file=massif.out
ms_print arguments: massif.out
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------


    GB
10.09^        #                                                               
     |        #                                                               
     |        #                                                               
     |        #                                                               
     |        #                                                               
     |        #                                                               
     |        #      @:::::@::::::::::::::::@@:::::@:::::@::::::@::::@:::::@::
     |        #      @:::::@: :::::::: :::: @@:::::@:::::@::::::@::::@:::::@::
     |        #::::::@:::::@: :::::::: :::: @@:::::@:::::@::::::@::::@:::::@::
     |        #::::: @:::::@: :::::::: :::: @@:::::@:::::@::::::@::::@:::::@::
     |        #::::: @:::::@: :::::::: :::: @@:::::@:::::@::::::@::::@:::::@::
     |        #::::: @:::::@: :::::::: :::: @@:::::@:::::@::::::@::::@:::::@::
     |        #::::: @:::::@: :::::::: :::: @@:::::@:::::@::::::@::::@:::::@::
     |        #::::: @:::::@: :::::::: :::: @@:::::@:::::@::::::@::::@:::::@::
     |        #::::: @:::::@: :::::::: :::: @@:::::@:::::@::::::@::::@:::::@::
     |        #::::: @:::::@: :::::::: :::: @@:::::@:::::@::::::@::::@:::::@::
     |        #::::: @:::::@: :::::::: :::: @@:::::@:::::@::::::@::::@:::::@::
     |        #::::: @:::::@: :::::::: :::: @@:::::@:::::@::::::@::::@:::::@::
     |     @  #::::: @:::::@: :::::::: :::: @@:::::@:::::@::::::@::::@:::::@::
     |  :::@::#::::: @:::::@: :::::::: :::: @@:::::@:::::@::::::@::::@:::::@::
   0 +----------------------------------------------------------------------->Gi
     0                                                                   8.927

Number of snapshots: 97
 Detailed snapshots: [7, 10 (peak), 17, 24, 43, 44, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90]

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  n        time(i)         total(B)   useful-heap(B) extra-heap(B)    stacks(B)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  0              0           16,384           16,384             0            0
  1    149,772,704      393,547,776      393,547,776             0            0
  2    243,902,287      398,592,800      398,592,800             0            0
  3    396,613,298      558,157,704      558,157,704             0            0
  4    504,752,503      638,138,760      638,138,760             0            0
  5    604,812,936      639,894,808      639,894,808             0            0
...
```

**Edit to add all children**:

To add all descendants (children) you can add the `--trace-children=yes` option to the `valgrind` command.

Comment: This would dump a whole lot of numbers to the screen every two seconds. How could you modify this to give the user the peak RAM usage, which is what they are actually asking about?

Comment: Also note that the question is about a process tree (i.e. a process and all its children and descendants), not about a single process.

Comment: @CAFxX If you are talking about `valgrind`, see my edit.  To measure all the descendants you simply add the `--trace-children=yes` parameter.  The Kusalananda comment was before I added the `valgrind` information.