What is the contribution of API to the memory usage of a process in linux as shown by pmap command?
I am trying to understand the memory usage of my program excluding the contribution of custom made API that creates and attaches to shared memory segment.
Following is the API code. I have included reasonably significant local memory allocation in the API.
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
using namespace std;

#define MAX_RECORDS 259200

typedef struct {
double Dummy_d ;
unsigned long int Dmmy_ui8;
}DummyStruct ;

int AttachToShmApi(key_t key,char *ErrMsg) {

        int LoopCount = 0;
        // Local memory declaration
        DummyStruct DummyRecord[MAX_RECORDS];

        // Initialize local memory
        for(LoopCount=0;LoopCount<MAX_RECORDS;++LoopCount) {
                DummyRecord[LoopCount].Dummy_d = 0.0 ;
                DummyRecord[LoopCount].Dmmy_ui8 = 0.0 ;
        }

        printf("\nSize of DummyRecord : %lu",sizeof(DummyRecord));
        // shmget returns an identifier in shmid
        int shmid = shmget(key, 1024, 0666 | IPC_CREAT);
        if (shmid == -1) {
                sprintf(ErrMsg,"AttachToShmApi : Shared memory creation problem");
                return -1 ;
        }

        char *shmp;
        // shmat to attach to shared memory
        shmp = (char*)shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);
        if (shmp == (void *) -1) {
                sprintf(ErrMsg,"AttachToShmApi : Shared memory attachment problem");
                return -1 ;
        }

        cout<<endl<<"Shared memory created with id : "<<shmid<<endl<<endl;

        return 1;
}


Now the program that invokes the API to attach to the shared memory segments.
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int AttachToShmApi(key_t,char *);

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
        if ( argc < 5 ) {
                cout<<endl<<"Usage : "<<argv[0]<<" Key1(numeric)"<< " Key2(numeric)"<< " Key3(numeric)"<< " Key4(numeric)"<<endl<<endl;
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        key_t key ;
        char ErrMsg[200];
        memset(ErrMsg,0,sizeof(ErrMsg));

        key = key_t(atoi(argv[1]));
        if ( AttachToShmApi(key,ErrMsg) <= 0 ) {
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        cout<<endl<<"Attached to 1st shared memory segment!!"<<endl;

        key = key_t(atoi(argv[2]));
        if ( AttachToShmApi(key,ErrMsg) <= 0 ) {
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        cout<<endl<<"Attached to 2nd shared memory segment!!"<<endl;

        key = key_t(atoi(argv[3]));
        if ( AttachToShmApi(key,ErrMsg) <= 0 ) {
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        cout<<endl<<"Attached to 3rd shared memory segment!!"<<endl;

        key = key_t(atoi(argv[4]));
        if ( AttachToShmApi(key,ErrMsg) <= 0 ) {
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        cout<<endl<<"Attached to 4th shared memory segment!!"<<endl;



        while(1) {

                sleep(1);
        }

        return 0;
}

I am trying to attach to 4 shared memory segments.
./ShmApiConnector3.exe 1500 2500 3500 4500

Size of DummyRecord : 4147200
Shared memory created with id : 196626


Attached to 1st shared memory segment!!

Size of DummyRecord : 4147200
Shared memory created with id : 196628


Attached to 2nd shared memory segment!!

Size of DummyRecord : 4147200
Shared memory created with id : 196629


Attached to 3rd shared memory segment!!

Size of DummyRecord : 4147200
Shared memory created with id : 196633


Attached to 4th shared memory segment!!

Following is the summarised output of pmap command.
mapped: 17944K    writeable/private: 4288K    shared: 16K

As we can see 16k shared output is contributed by 1 page ( 4096 bytes ) each of 4 shared memory segments.
Now I have written another program to independently attach to 4 shared memory segments.
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
        if ( argc < 5 ) {
                cout<<endl<<"Usage : "<<argv[0]<<" Key1(numeric)"<< " Key2(numeric)"<< " Key3(numeric)"<< " Key4(numeric)"<<endl<<endl;
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        key_t key ;
        int shmid ;

        key = key_t(atoi(argv[1]));

        // shmget returns an identifier in shmid
        shmid = shmget(key, 1024, 0644 | IPC_CREAT);
        if (shmid == -1) {
                perror("Shared memory");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        char* str1;
        // shmat to attach to shared memory
        str1 = (char*)shmat(shmid, (void*)0, 0);
        if (str1 == (void *) -1) {
                perror("Shared memory not attached!!");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        cout<<endl<<"Attached to 1st shared memory segment!!"<<endl;
        key = key_t(atoi(argv[2]));

        // shmget returns an identifier in shmid
        shmid = shmget(key, 1024, 0644 | IPC_CREAT);
        if (shmid == -1) {
                perror("Shared memory");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        char* str2;
        // shmat to attach to shared memory
        str2 = (char*)shmat(shmid, (void*)0, 0);
        if (str2 == (void *) -1) {
                perror("Shared memory not attached!!");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        cout<<endl<<"Attached to 2nd shared memory segment!!"<<endl;

        key = key_t(atoi(argv[3]));

        // shmget returns an identifier in shmid
        shmid = shmget(key, 1024, 0644 | IPC_CREAT);
        if (shmid == -1) {
                perror("Shared memory");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        char* str3;
        // shmat to attach to shared memory
        str3 = (char*)shmat(shmid, (void*)0, 0);
        if (str3 == (void *) -1) {
                perror("Shared memory not attached!!");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        cout<<endl<<"Attached to 3rd shared memory segment!!"<<endl
key = key_t(atoi(argv[4]));

        // shmget returns an identifier in shmid
        shmid = shmget(key, 1024, 0644 | IPC_CREAT);
        if (shmid == -1) {
                perror("Shared memory");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        char* str4;
        // shmat to attach to shared memory
        str4 = (char*)shmat(shmid, (void*)0, 0);
        if (str4 == (void *) -1) {
                perror("Shared memory not attached!!");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        cout<<endl<<"Attached to 4th shared memory segment!!"<<endl;


        while(1) {

                sleep(1);
        }

        return 0;
}

Following is the summarised output of pmap command.
mapped: 14012K    writeable/private: 356K    shared: 16K

The difference between 2 approach is the presence of API in one approach.
My doubt is why writeable/private: 4288K, when API is used but writeable/private: 356K when API is not used ?
Test environment.
Linux soumajit-HP-Pavilion-Desktop-590-p0xxx 5.4.0-71-generic #79~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 25 05:45:39 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

You could try my peak monitoring if that may help you - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/725865/how-to-measure-peak-memory-usage-of-a-process-tree/734513#734513
